# Original text by Bertrand Russell describing his Barber Paradox?

Tags: math-history, paradoxes

I am looking for an authoritative online source that gives the original text by Bertrand Russell describing his Barber Paradox.

[Quine](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~langeh/test/1976%20-%20Quine%20-%20The%20Ways%20of%20Paradox%20and%20other%20Essays.pdf) described it like this:

> In a certain village there is a man, so the paradox runs, who is a
>   barber; this barber shaves all and only those men in the village who
>   do not shave themselves. Query: Does the barber shave himself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe he first used this language in his essay ["The philosophy of logical atomism"](https://sites.ualberta.ca/~francisp/NewPhil448/RussellPhilLogicalAtomismPears.pdf) (page $101$). He attributes this to an unnamed individual.

---

The text around this description is interesting, particularly the line

> In this form the contradiction is not very difficult
>   to solve.

I think what Russell means here is that it is clear that there is no such barber, *and this conclusion is in no way problematic*. By contrast, the version about classes is much more disturbing, since (he argues)

> I think it is clear that you can
>   only get around it by observing that the whole question whether
>   a class is or is not a member of itself is nonsense, i.e. that no class
>   either is or is not a member of itself, and that it is not even true
>   to say that, because the whole form of words is just a noise
>   without meaning. That has to do with the fact that classes, as I
>   shall be coming on to show, are incomplete symbols in the same
>   sense in which the descriptions are that I was talking of last time;
>   you are talking nonsense when you ask yourself whether a class
>   is or is not a member of itself, because in any full statement of
>   what is meant by a proposition which seems to be about a class,
>   you will find that the class is not mentioned at all and that there
>   is nothing about a class in that statement. It is absolutely necessary,
>   if a statement about a class is to be significant and not
>   pure nonsense, that it should be capable of being translated
>   into a form in which it does not mention the class at all.

Although the logical forms are the same, the barber version doesn't force us to draw any interesting conclusions, whereas the "pure" forms do.

Comment: Incidentally, this is the source given by [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barber_paradox#cite_note-atomism-1) for the Barber Paradox.

Comment: Here is the quote from Russell: "You can define the barber as 'one who shaves all those, and those only, who do not shave themselves'. The question is, does the barber shave himself?" So, Quine added the bit about "men in the village." I much prefer that version. Thanks Noah!